# document.activeElement returns [object HTMLInputElement], but instance of HTMLInputElement equals false?

Tags: javascript

i'm testing to see whether or not the current focused element is an input using document.activeElement. When it is [object HTMLInputElement] is returned, so i presumed that i'd be able to use the logic below to test this, but it always returns false?

```
document.activeElement instanceof HTMLInputElement
```

Anyone know what i'm doing wrong, as a quick search on google suggests this logic is perfectly valid?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the context to this question - some code, perhaps? This works quite fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nCT7X/).

Comment: thanks raina, this is not a good start to my Stackoverflow career! I was calling console.log( "a string" + document.activeElement instanceof HTMLInputElement) and forgot to wrap the condition in parenthesis, thus it was always returning false. It's been one of those days...

Comment: Can you provide more context and what browser you are doing this in? In this JSFiddle what you are describing works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/jzQ6B/

Answer (score -1):

use hasfocus method.

**activeElement** Returns a reference to the object that is currently designated as the active element in the document.

Only one element can be active at a time in a document. An active element does not necessarily have focus, but an element with focus is always the active element in a document. For example, an active element within a window that is not the foreground window has no focus.